# Syntax error at position 57 in 'TimeZoneStandard='microsoft.graph.timeZoneStandard'Iana'''

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to request the supported timezones in the IANA format for a user (in Java), and getting the following error:

```
Error code: RequestBroker--ParseUri
Error message: Syntax error at position 57 in 'TimeZoneStandard='microsoft.graph.timeZoneStandard'Iana'''.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/email@redacted.com/outlook/microsoft.graph.supportedTimeZones(TimeZoneStandard=microsoft.graph.timeZoneStandard'Iana')
SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.3.1
Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]


400 : Bad Request
[...]
```

Based on our test suit, the request was working fine 3 days ago, and started failing with that error yesterday. We haven't changed anything for a while on our implementation, so I'm a bit baffled. For the request I'm essentially doing the following:

```java
final String url = requestBuilder.outlook()
    .getRequestUrlWithAdditionalSegment("microsoft.graph.supportedTimeZones(TimeZoneStandard=microsoft.graph.timeZoneStandard'Iana')");
final OutlookUserSupportedTimeZonesCollectionRequestBuilder builder = new OutlookUserSupportedTimeZonesCollectionRequestBuilder(
    url, requestBuilder.getClient(), null
);
IOutlookUserSupportedTimeZonesCollectionPage page = builder.buildRequest().get();
```

The reason I'm doing this instead of the standard:

```
final IOutlookUserSupportedTimeZonesCollectionPage page = requestBuilder.outlook()
    .supportedTimeZones(TimeZoneStandard.IANA)
    .buildRequest()
    .get();
```

Is because this isn't working as expected, as described here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/7594 (the issue is for C#, but happens in Java too).

What I notice is that the GET url looks fine, and works fine in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) using the `/me` endpoint instead of the `/users` endpoint. But the string in the error message looks modified:

```
'TimeZoneStandard='microsoft.graph.timeZoneStandard'Iana'''
```

If I'm not mistaken, the outer apostrophes are simply quoting done when printing the error message, but there are further apostrophes introduced after the `=` sign, which aren't present in the GET URI, which might be causing the syntax error. Still, I have no idea where those come from.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have modified the call something like this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UPN/outlook/supportedTimeZones(TimeZoneStandard='Iana')`. It worked for me.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma Thanks, as far as I could test that seems to be working fine! You should post it as an answer instead of simply a comment. Let's hope there is some official response from Microsoft (either update their documentation or fix the parser issue they introduced).

Comment: Hi contiver, glad to hear that it worked for you. Please accept it as answer by clicking the check mark so that it could be helpful to others. :)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the call something like this

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UPN/outlook/supportedTimeZones(TimeZoneStandard='Iana')`

It worked for me.